# Is there any way to find the derivative of a scalar value with respect to a vector using python?

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, derivative

I am trying to write a loss function. My loss function produces the value 112.314. I am trying to find the derivative of this loss function with respect to some weights, which is a vector. The vector is [3.7, 3.7, 3.9, 4.3, 2.5, 3.3, 4.7].

Up until now what I have tried is `np.gradient(112.314, [3.7, 3.7, 3.9, 4.3, 2.5, 3.3, 4.7])`.

Comment: You can't find the gradient of a function with respect to your weights without knowing what the function is. Just knowing the value of the function with those inputs is not enough.

Comment: the function is mse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this explanation](https://mccormickml.com/2014/03/04/gradient-descent-derivation/) of gradient descent using the derivative of MSE. In short the gradient of MSE is the sum of the differences between your predicted values and the true values.

But this still doesn't tell you the gradient with respect to your weights, that's just the gradient with respect to the predictions - you'll also need to substitute your model function for h(x) in equation 1.4 at the link, and use chain rule to get the gradient with respect to your weights. He shows the result of this for the case of linear regression.